How to disable chrome notification popups while automating in selenium java?
How to disable chrome notification popups
I have tried that below code but its not working
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    option.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

    


Try:

options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");

See - How do i stop the blocking of redirects in my chromedriver?

I hope you do not care much about the session, cookies, or cache data. If not then that particular notification can be disabled in incognito mode. So for that you can alter your code as below
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("--incognito");//This would open the Chrome in incognito mode and it would block most of the popups
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);

